# <li> too big in height, horizontal nav bar with img with <ul>

Tags: html, css, image, navbar

I am trying to make a navbar with imag, I don't know what to do because the main problem is that the image has to be resized but when it's done the 'li' tag are too big in height and I don't know how to deal with it and I don't know where it's from. Basically, i'm trying to do a navabar with images with the same height but when I'm dealing with the  there is an extra space. I did some research but I found nothing about this `<li>` problem.

Here some code for example :

```css
#bas_page ul{
 list-style: none;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 padding:0;
 height: 80px;
 width: 90%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 vertical-align: center;
}

#bas_page li{
 display: inline-block;
}

.icon_contact{
 height: 100%;
}

#bas_page #mon_email{
 background: white;
 position: relative;
 color: #50667F;
 font-size: 100%; 
 padding: 5%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer id="bas_page">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png"  class="icon_contact" alt="My Facebook"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJ_YIhdykKf9oMnK1G1qIpiE7PREjJD_xHSQLP6nThnf2PMLE9" class="icon_contact" alt="My Linkedin"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p id="mon_email" class="icon_contact">ffffff@gmail.com</p></a></li>
   </ul>
  </footer>
```

**SOLUTION**

It's from the `<img>` and not the `<li>`

```
vertical-align
```

here I found some [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: not clear what you expect at the end

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: well, does anyone know why my post is still downvoted? I applied all of the advices in the guide

Comment: Did what I can from my side :)

Comment: yes i saw thank you ! hopefully a moderator will tell me what's wrong with my post because i really tried to apply all the advices

Answer (score 0):

In order to control your image size, you can use `.icon_contact` class. And define the `width` and `height` and in `mon-email` , `font-size` to same units

**Snippet**

```css
#bas_page ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#bas_page li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#bas_page #mon_email {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  color: #50667F;
  font-size:2em;
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
.icon_contact {
  width:2rem;
  height:2rem;
}
```

```html
<footer id="bas_page">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png" class="icon_contact" alt="My Facebook"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJ_YIhdykKf9oMnK1G1qIpiE7PREjJD_xHSQLP6nThnf2PMLE9" class="icon_contact" alt="My Linkedin"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <p id="mon_email" class="icon_contact">ffffff@gmail.com</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: indeed but i want it to get the same size as the paragraph its why i put height = 100% to fit the with the container's size but the width of the <li> is too large.

Comment: so you want to get text and the images both into same size?

Comment: yes that's it i made some chagnes but i dont know why it works, i'll post it

Comment: use "rem" units instead of percentages, it will define a fixed width and height, also it is responsive.

Comment: ok i changed my code and see now on microsoft edge when i add padding the text move outside the paragraph instead of resizing the background like on firefox

Comment: Use rem units without using pixels. And at the same time help me with my answer as well.

Comment: i did, see my edit on my 'updated code' post , and help ? what do you mean ? because i can't upvote, i have less than 15 reputations

Comment: done !  thank you !  can you check my edit i see a new problem :/ but thank a lot for what you already did !

Comment: nope i fixed it thank you ! i just re-write ma code again because it was a big mess

Comment: That&#39;s great! Btw for other people&#39;s reference, you can edit my answer so viewers can get a help, otherwise this question is incomplete